# Mongoose auto increment by not replacing ID field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There are many Mongoose auto increment stack overflow questions and answers out there, but all of them want to replace the Mongoose ID with an incrementing number. I do not want to replace the ID, I just want an extra field named `index` that will hold an incrementing number. I know this might not make sense but it is what I need. Is there anything like this?

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    index: {
        type: Number,
        autoIncrement: true // something like this?
    }
});
```

So I would like the `index` field to auto increment `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)`. I don't really care if it starts at `0` or `1`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Is `autoIncrement: true` a valid statement? I updated my question with a more direct question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no such option supported out of the box. You can, however, achieve this programmatically.

What you'll want to do is create a separate collection. Using this new collection, you can perform a `findOneAndUpdate()` call that performs an `$inc`rement operation on the `counter` field (or your preferred alternative) for the document with the option `upsert: true` applied. By setting the option `new: true`, you will also get the updated version of the document rather than the original.

Once the `findOneAndUpdate()` call completes, you will receive a document that contains a sequential integer value starting at 1. You may then grab that value from the `counter` field and store it in the document where you wanted this value originally. If you want that value to start at 0, just insert the value offset by `-1`.

This will result in the new collection starting with no documents, then having exactly one document starting after your first `findOneAndUpdate()` call that will only ever have its `counter` field updated repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hook to achieving autoIncrement in loopback.

> Example : `increment` some field after save. May help you

```
Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {

  const ModelCollection = Model.getDataSource().connector.collection("Model");
  let id = ctx.instance.id; //get id which are save.
  ModelCollection.update(id, {
    $inc: {
      index: 1
    }
  }, {
      multi: true
    });
  next();
});
```